# How to show all contacts on google map in salesforce(visualforce page)

Tags: apex-code, visualforce, apex

Could you guys provide me apex code to show all contacts on google map in visualforce page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works properly,

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_vf_mapping_components.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a google maps/JS question, most of the work would be setting up the client side to display the items on a google map.  The Salesforce part of this would be a simple SOQL query on account to get the address of contacts that you want to show.  The only thing would be to decide how you would pass the list of contacts back to the client, either remote action, public property or getter.